# When trying to HTTP POST to a simple ASPNET Core 2 website, the Action Method is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

#### Summary

I'm misunderstanding the default routing of a simple/basic ASPNET-Core 2 MVC Web App.

#### Details

I'm trying to do a simple HTTP Post to my ASPNET-Core 2 website but I get unexpected response statuses.

[Sample code all found in a GitHub Repo](https://github.com/PureKrome/TestWebApplication) I quickly pushed up.

I'm trying to create the following route:

`HTTP POST /test`

which returns a `201 CREATED`.

I've got the following route setup in my `Setup` class:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

#### Attempt #1

Now the following results occur when I do an `HTTP POST` in Postman:

```
Route      | Result | Expectation
/test      | 404    | 201
/test/post | 201    | 404
/          | 200    | 404 Da Faq?? (this is because the HomeController INDEX method 
                                    handled this)
```

I'm expecting a `201` when I HTTP POST to `/test/post`.

Code:

```
TestController.cs

public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(FakeVehicle fakeVehicle) { .. }
}
```

#### Attempt #2

That said, when I decorate the controller with a `[Route("test")\]` attribute, I start to get different results...

```
TestController.cs

[Route("test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(FakeVehicle fakeVehicle) { .. }
}
```

and the routes I try:

```
Route      | Result | Expectation
/test      | 201    | 201 YAY!
/test/post | 404    | 404 YAY!
/          | 200    | 404 Da Faq?? (this is because the HomeController INDEX method 
                                    handled this)
```

#### But wait, there's more!

If I change my `Startup` class to the following:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

where I don't provide any default route rules, I get the following now:

No `[Route]` attribute decorated:

```
Route      | Result | Expectation
/test      | 201    | 404
/test/post | 404    | 404
/          | 404    | 404
```

With the `[Route]` attribute decorated:

```
Route      | Result | Expectation
/test      | 201    | 201
/test/post | 404    | 404
/          | 404    | 404
```

The very last one is the most accurate. So why does the default route map make things all weird, please?

Comment: `/test` matches the default route and passes `test` as the `controller`, but because you do not have a segment for the `action` it uses the default (effectively `/test/index`) - do you have an `Index()` method on that controller (which would result in a 404 if not)

Comment: @StephenMuecke here's https://github.com/PureKrome/TestWebApplication/blob/master/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L6

Comment: That's the `HomeController` :)

Comment: Oh. there's no `Index()` method on the `TestController`. I misunderstood the comment, above. Ref: https://github.com/PureKrome/TestWebApplication/blob/master/Controllers/TestController.cs#L11

Comment: That would explain the 404 when using `/Test`